# Building a General Tree in C++ using Vectors and Queues

Tags: c++, tree, queue

For a project for one of my classes, I am required to parse data using RapidXML from an xml file and create a tree from that data. I've been thinking about how to how to do this for days and have just been going in circles. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me get  this down conceptually.

Each xml node has a name attribute and child nodes and I want to be able to access the lineage of any given node, so I think that the treeNode class will have a name variable and a vector of pointers to its children. Does this sound correct so far?

I'm getting extremely confused about how to create the nodes once I add them to the queue and how to build the tree with these nodes. I'm not sure how to distinguish which node is a child of which. Here is the method I have for parsing the xml file. It parses and outputs correctly, I just don't know how to store these nodes in a tree data structure.

```
void oneQueue(xml_node<> *xml)
{
    //Initialize queue
    queue<xml_node<>* > q;

    int nodesInCurrentLevel =1;
    int nodesInNextLevel =0;
    //push the first xml node onto the queue
    q.push(xml);

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        //grab the xml node at the front of the queue
        xml_node<> *currNode = q.front();
        xml_node<> *name = currNode->first_node("name");

        //make a node from the xml node
        Node *node = new Node();
        //IF the name has a value, set the name
        if(name != 0) node->setName(name->value());
        q.pop();
        nodesInCurrentLevel--;

        if(node)
        {
            cout << node->getName() << endl;
            //loop through the children of the node and add to the queue
            for(xml_node<> * species = currNode->first_node("species"); species; species = species->next_sibling())
            {
                q.push(species);
                nodesInNextLevel++;
            }
        }
        if (nodesInCurrentLevel == 0) {
            nodesInCurrentLevel = nodesInNextLevel;
            nodesInNextLevel = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Trees are a new concept to me and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why do you need a queue? I can see it only in the title, the tag, and some definitions in the code. AFAIK if you use DOM parser it internally creates a tree for you that you can traverse. Is it a requirement to put all the stuff from DOM tree into some construct of queues and vectors?

Comment: @mlt This is the file I am parsing http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cop3530sp13/projects/species.xml I have to do a breath first traversal to get the proper tree format. My TA suggested we do the traversal using a queue. Add the xml node to the queue and create a treeNode from each xml node in the queue then add it to the tree then pop off the xml node. We are required to use RapidXMl and parse the data ourselves into a tree structure

Comment: Are you trying to manually perform XML transformation and create another DOM tree with a flattened listing of extracted species? If so then once you got nodes into the tree, you can create another DOM tree by appending nodes to a new document node as [it is shown in the manual](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1modifying_dom_tree). Otherwise it is not clear what constitutes the essence of the question. Do you want to preserve the structure and copy everything into a new document node the hard way by keeping everything in intermediate C++ objects?

Comment: @mlt I'm new to c++ so I'm not quite sure what a DOM tree is. The instructions I was given for this project are to parse an XML containing a phylogenetic tree and build my own tree structure that can be searched in various ways. Each xml node represents a taxonomy object that I will be making.